# Debugging installed libraries

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code

I have installed `mbedtls` on my wsl Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libmbedtls-dev
```

But I would like to debug through library code. I have downloaded source files from git repository. But does it means I must build libraries with `-g` option which allows produce debugging information?

Comment: Is there a dbg package for the library?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

Comment: Also you might want to add tag for your Likix distro.